# Perform lookup and update within a single Django query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two models: `MetaModel` and `RelatedModel`. I want to include the result of a `RelatedModel` lookup within a `MetaModel` query, and I'd like to do this within a single DB call.

I've tried to define a 'subquery' QuerySet for use in the main query, but that hasn't worked - it's still making two queries to complete the operation.

*Note:* I can't use a traditional `ForeignKey` relationship because the `profile_id` field is not unique. Uniqueness is a combination of `profile_id` and `channel`. This is an aggregation table and `profile_id` is not guaranteed to be unique across multiple third-party channels.

Any suggestions?

**Models:**

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
    )

class MetaModel(models.Model):
    profile_id = fields.IntegerField()
    channel = fields.ForeignKey(Channel))
    metadata = fields.TextField()

class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    related_id = fields.IntegerField()
    profile_id = fields.IntegerField()
    channel = fields.ForeignKey(Channel))
```

**Dummy data**

```
channel = Channel("Web site A")
channel.save()

sample_meta = MetaModel(profile_id=1234, channel=channel)
sample_related = RelatedModel(profile_id=1234, related_id=5678, channel=channel)
```

**Query:**

```
# Create a queryset to filter down to the single record we need the `profile_id` for
# I've limited to the only field we need via a `values` operation 
related_qs = RelatedAccount.objects.filter(
    related_id=5678,
    channel=channel
).values_list("profile_id", flat=True)

# I'm doing an update_or_create as there is other data to store, not included for brevity
obj, created = MetaModel.objects.update_or_create(
    profile_id=related_qs.first(),  # <<< This var is the dynamic part of the query
    channel=channel,
    defaults={"metadata": "Metadata is added to a new or existing record."}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your note on uniqueness, you can use `unique_together` option in Django as described here in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

```
class MetaModel(models.Model):
    profile_id = fields.ForeignKey(RelatedModel)
    channel = fields.ForeignKey(Channel)
    metadata = fields.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile_id', 'channel')
```

Then you can change your query accordingly and should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Borut, I didn't know about `unique_together`. It won't actually help on this occasion unfortunately - for legacy reasons, the profile records for each channel exist within different models and tables so I can't link to a single Model via ForeignKey. You have inspired me to look into merging these models at a later date now this `unique_together` / compound approach is available.

Comment: @PhilSheard, when you said that you have tried `subquery`, do you mean [subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) introduced in version 1.11?

Comment: No, I didn't know that existed actually. I was trying to infer a subquery by passing a queryset as a parameter, but an explicity `Subquery()` could be what I'm after. Thank you, I'll give that a try.